# Why do we have first/every-visit in MC but not last visit

Tags: monte-carlo, reinforcement-learning

I'm studying Reinforcement Learning and I just read about first-visit and every-visit Monte Carlo, however I don't get why we are not considering last-visit MC as a possible simulation.

My "last visit" comes from the fact that if we have a sequence of states $S_0, ..., S_T$ and we see the state $s$ the last time at time $t$ (i mean $S_t = s, \forall t' > t S_{t'} \ne s$), then that is the "shortest path" from state $s$ to the goal, so that's already a "good" evaluation, everything before that time $t$ is theoretically just "loops" or random walks in the states